# Place a text box inside table cell but with no margin and padding. Text box should fit the cell completely

Tags: html, css

I tried this. Even I added padding and margin to "0" in table properties but it didn't worked for me.

```
<td><textarea class="myTextarea" >Content</textarea></td>
```

CSS:

```
.myTextarea
{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try this - table { border-collapse: collapse;}

Comment: did you tried `border:0`

Comment: I tried both but didn't worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Quick brute force fix: negative margins

Answer (score 0):

Add Border:0;

```
.myTextarea {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Making the value of border to 0 makes the border of the text box disappear but the size of the text box is still same. It is not covering the complete cell.

Comment: You need to set padding and margin of td  to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
Input[Type='text']{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: This css makes the text field completely fill its parent, which in this case is corresponding table cell having text field. Also setting border 0 removes border around the text field to merge it completely in table cell.

Comment: Nothing changed. Only the size of the text box get changed inside the cell but still text box is not covering the complete cell.